# Why apt-file does not show which package contains specific file?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, logs

I have Ubuntu 21.04 and gtk:

```
ldconfig -v | grep libgtk    
    libgtk-3.so.0 -> libgtk-3.so.0.2404.21
    libgtksourceview-4.so.0 -> libgtksourceview-4.so.0.0.0
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 -> libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.33
    libgtkmm-3.0.so.1 -> libgtkmm-3.0.so.1.1.0
    libgtk-1.2.so.0 -> libgtk.so
```

In the apt history is :

```
less /var/log/apt/history.log
Start-Date: 2021-07-18  14:56:44
Commandline: apt install ./libglib1.2ldbl_1.2.10-19_amd64.deb
Requested-By: a (1000)
Install: libglib1.2ldbl:amd64 (1.2.10-19)
End-Date: 2021-07-18  14:56:44

Start-Date: 2021-07-18  14:58:00
Commandline: apt install ./libgtk1.2-common_1.2.10-18.1_all.deb
Requested-By: a (1000)
Install: libgtk1.2-common:amd64 (1.2.10-18.1)
Remove: libgtk1.2-common:i386 (1.2.10-18)
End-Date: 2021-07-18  14:58:00

Start-Date: 2021-07-18  14:59:24
Commandline: apt install ./libgtk1.2_1.2.10-18.1_amd64.deb
Requested-By: a (1000)
Install: libgtk1.2:amd64 (1.2.10-18.1)
End-Date: 2021-07-18  14:59:25
```

but apt-file can not find it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search '/lib/libgtk-1.2.so.0'
apt-file search '/lib/libglib-1.2.so.0'
```

What is the reason ?

=== edit ===

```
 dpkg -S 'libgtk-1.2.so.0'
libgtk1.2: /usr/lib/libgtk-1.2.so.0
libgtk1.2: /usr/lib/libgtk-1.2.so.0.9.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-file` only shows files in packages available in configured repositories; it doesn’t know about packages installed locally.

To search in locally-installed packages, use `dpkg`’s `-S` feature, for example

```
dpkg -S libgtk-1.2.so.0
```

Comment: Does ti mean that if I install from local file then it is installed locally, but when I install from  configured repositories then it is installed globally ?

Comment: No, packages you install are installed locally, you don’t affect any other system. But repositories maintain indexes of the packages they serve, and that’s what `apt-file` uses; so it can only find files in packages which are available from the system’s configured repositories. It can’t find files in packages which are obtained elsewhere.